# Angular ui-route testing using mocha chai and sinon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I need to test below code in angularjs using mocha chai and sinon

```
$scope.send = function() {
    $state.transitionTo('module.sendhome');
};
```

Below is test case for the same

```
it('send' , function () {
    scope.send();
});
```

on running the above test case getting error as given below.
Error: No such state 'module.sendhome'

In my test case need to check if $state.transitionTo is called with parameter **module.sendhome**.

Comment: As an aside, use `$state.go`. `$state.go` calls `$state.transitionTo` under the hood, but sets some common settings. [Relevant docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stub out `$state` and the `transitionTo` method and write expectations on that. This will keep your unit test clean and flexible, so as to not trigger the real implementation of `$state.transitionTo` (which in turn triggers the error you are experiencing).

```
var $scope, $state;

beforeEach(function () {
  $state = {};

  module('your_module', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$state', $state);
  });

  inject(function ($injector, $controller) {
    $state = $injector.get('$state');
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

    $controller('your_controller', {
      $scope: $scope,
      $state: $state
    });
  });

  // Stub API
  $state.transitionTo = sinon.stub();
});


it('calls the transitionTo method', function () {
  $scope.send();
  expect($state.transitionTo).to
    .have.been.calledOnce
    .and.calledWith('module.sendhome');
});
```

---

#### Edit

As per the notion of [not stubbing out things we do not own](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html) (which, I don't fully agree on but for the sake of argument let's say I do).

Don't `stub` $state.transitionTo, but rather `spy` on it.

Now - you will have to register a state matching that of your expectation in order for $state.transitionTo to not crash.

```
var stateProvider;

beforeEach(function () {
  module('ui.router', function ($stateProvider) {
    stateProvider = $stateProvider;
  });

  /** The rest of your beforeEach block **/ 

  stateProvider.state('module.sendhome', {});
});
```

And then in your `it`:

```
it('calls the transitionTo method with the correct params', function () {
  var spy = sinon.spy($state, 'transitionTo');
  $scope.send();
  expect(spy).to
    .have.been.calledOnce
    .and.calledWith('module.sendhome');
});
```

---

### Edit#2

If you want to ensure that you ended up on the correct `state` after invoking your `$scope` method, I would look into [this awesomely awesome stateMock](https://gist.github.com/geraldofcneto/7d4690dc8c81b0f1fde0).

Inject `stateMock` as another module prior to your own and write expectations such as:

```
afterEach(function () {
  $state.ensureAllTransitionsHappened();
});

it('should travel to the correct state', function () {
  $state.expectTransitionTo('module.sendhome');
  $scope.send();
});
```

Comment: although, please see [this article](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html) about mocking/stubbing types you don't own.

Comment: Fair point. I'll add an addition to the answer on how to get this passing with the $state implementation left intact.

Comment: @DanPantry I've added another section on how to keep the third party implementation intact, setting expectations on its usage and ensuring that it does not crash the build. What do you reckon?

Comment: I think the point of the article given is not to avoid overwriting the method itself but to actually avoid testing (at this level) that you actually interact with that collaborator. So instead of unit testing that you invoke X method with Y parameters, you do an integration test that verifies that before the method you're in state A and after you're in state B.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not a unit test - now we're moving into the land of integration testing which is a lot slower and high level than a unit test. But to be fair, the OP never did mention if he wanted to write a full fletched integration test or a unit test.

Comment: That's true. I do (in my answers) tend to point out when I personally feel an OP's approach is somewhat incorrect, but obviously that is my opinion.

Comment: That's fair - I find myself doing the same thing a lot of the time(s), but in this particular case I feel a unit test is preferred over a full on integration test given the nature of the question; `"In my test case need to check if $state.transitionTo is called with parameter module.sendhome."` An integration test wouldn't care about this sort of detail at all as far as I'm concerned.